# Socket.io application in practice

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Are there any socket.io projects/applications used in production?

I just wonder because I want to use it for a huge project, and I did not find any articles about companies/projects using socket.io.

Answer (score 1):

we've used socket.io for faster UI updates with (financial) price information in production.  It does its job on the client side.  There is more load on the server side (as opposed to just AJAX which is understandable) - one needs to set up/configure flash sockets if you wish to use it as a fallback.  Most browsers will fall back and not use web sockets (unless they are using chrome).

Comment: This is incorrect. First of all both FireFox and Chrome use WebSockets and together they have more then 50% of browser market share, which means that most clients **will not** fall back. And secondly: WebSockets do create havier load, but doing the same thing without them (for example long polling) is a lot worse. If you have to implement real-time notifications, then WebSockets is the best way to do that.

Comment: yes, my choice of words i.e. most, was not completely accurate - however, web sockets are not set up by default in older versions of FF.  hope it helps

Comment: ok. but are there any well known projects/companies using socket.io?

Comment: I'm not sure about companies that are using it - I shared my experience and its for a real time app.  This is my personal opinion so its ok if others deem it as incorrect.  I would consider socket.io (or any decent wrapper around websockets) for applications within a company/intranet (or limited number of paying customers)

Comment: if you're developing for the internet and you're targeting scale, yoy will end up using more VM's as opposed to relying on AJAX (this might not be a concern to you though) - though if real time messaging is important (& you realize that not all users on the internet will have browsers with pre-configured websockets), then socket.io (or any wrapper around web sockets with fallbacks in place) can be used.